# Updating non-reactive values in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have the following example:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  textOutput("out"),
  actionButton("plusX", "Increase X"),
  actionButton("redraw", "redraw")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  x <- 0
  observeEvent(input$plusX, {x <<- x+1})
  output$out <- renderText({
    input$redraw
    x
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Is this considered an anti-pattern in Shiny to modify a non-reactive variable in this way? Obviating the super assignment which can be problematic by itself.

I know this could be done, for example with a reactiveVal to store X, and isolate to obtain a similar result. This second way seems clearer and that would be my usual choice, but I was wondering if there any caveats in the first one, or it is possible way of doing that.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  textOutput("out"),
  actionButton("plusX", "Increase X"),
  actionButton("redraw", "redraw")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  x <- reactiveVal(0)
  observeEvent(input$plusX, {x(x()+1)})
  output$out <- renderText({
    input$redraw
    isolate(x())
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Why do say that `<<-`  can be problematic? I don't see any problem in your app.

Comment: By problematic I mean that you are breaking the scope of the observe which in my opinion, and I think as a general programming consensus, should be avoided when possible. The app works fine, I was just thinking if there is any particular issue that could be caused in the first case for modifying non-reactive values or any known caveats in this approach.

Comment: Great question IMHO. I prefer the 2nd proposal.
NB: When I make many calls to `isolate(x())` to get the value, I define a classical (non-reactive) function within in server's code to retrieve this value.

Answer (score 1):

In this example there is no important difference between both codes as you are not using the benefit of ReactiveVal.

The benefit of ReactiveVal is that it has a reactive nature and thus can interact with other reactive elements.

Try for example to add a table to your code that depends on x:

```
output$tab <- renderTable({data.frame(y = x)})
```

(x() in the case of ReactiveVal)

The difference you will see that in the case of ReactiveVal the table automatically updates with plusX whereas in the case of the regular variable it does not update.

Comment: Thanks, I understand that the most immediate effect is the lack of reactivity, I was wondering if this is a common approach that other Shiny programmers use against for example the second which seems more natural to me.

Comment: Yea, I would personally also always use a reactiveVal. Once you start expanding on an application reactivity might become important and there is no obvious merit in keeping variables non-reactive.